# Role of info-plist

Tags: xcode

can someone briefly explain that what is exactly the role of info-plist in xcode project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of a typical Info.plist file convey the following information to the system:

- The user-visible name to display for
  the bundle
- A unique identifier string
  (typically in the form
  com.yourcompany.appname) that can be
  used to locate the bundle at runtime
- The type of the bundle (application,
  framework, plug-in)
- Version
  information
- The preferred execution environment for the bundle
- Information about the bundle’s supported document types (if any)
- For iPhone applications, information
  about how the application presents content initially

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/115-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html

Comment: Above links are stale/broken.  Here are some current replacements: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW105    https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Reference/Java_InfoplistRef/Articles/JavaDictionaryInfo.plistKeys.html